# Count data if existing in other table

Tags: mysql, sql, count

My query with a few INNER JOINs generate a result like this:

```
File_ID | Folder_ID |        email               | name
   1          4        user@mydomain.com           User1
   2          4        user2@differentdomain.com   User2
   3          4        user3@NOTmydomain.com       User3
```

I also have a table for all the users in my domain.

```
Email                |
---------------------| 
user1@mydomain.com   |
user2@mydomain.com   |
user3@mydomain.com   |
```

Now I want to compare and count the result of the first table on how many data in the results are with `LIKE '@mydomain.com' but NOT EXISTS/ NOT IN the Email table`. So in this example the result of the `COUNT = 0` since `user@mydomain` is not on the Email table even it has `'@mydomain.com'`.`

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, Could you provide your table structure

Comment: Please check: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index